# Getting root and intermediate certificates from an end-entity

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

still being a noob in cryptography I stumble upon simple things every day. And today is just one of those days.

I want to validate smime messages in java with the bouncy castle library, and I think I almost figured it out, but the problem at this moment is the building of the PKIXparameters object. 
Let's say, I have an end-entity x509certificate with the following structure:

```
root certificate
 +->intermediate certificate
    +->end-entity certificate
```

In order to validate message I need to build a chain of trust first, but I cannot figure out how to extract a root and intermediate certificates from the end-entity.

I tried to use end-entity as root but it didn't work:

```
InputStream isCert = GetFISCertificate();

List list = new ArrayList();
X509Certificate rootCert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(isCert);
list.add(rootCert);
CollectionCertStoreParameters params = new CollectionCertStoreParameters(list);
CertStore store = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", params, BC);

//create cert path
List certChain = new ArrayList();
certChain.add(rootCert);
CertPath certPath = certificateFactory.generateCertPath(certChain);
Set trust = Collections.singleton(new TrustAnchor(rootCert, null));

//validation
CertPathValidator certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX", BC);
PKIXParameters pKIXParameters = new PKIXParameters(trust);
pKIXParameters.addCertStore(store);
pKIXParameters.setDate(new Date());
try {
CertPathValidatorResult result = certPathValidator.validate(certPath, pKIXParameters);
System.out.println("certificate path validated");

} catch (CertPathValidatorException e) {
System.out.println("validation failed on certificate number " + e.getIndex() + ", details: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Got this exception:

```
validation failed on certificate number -1, details: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

And btw, can I just use only the end-entity certificate to validate messages, as if it were the self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used **BouncyCastle 1.56** for this test.

One way to get the issuer's certificate from the end entity is to look for the [**Authority Information Access** extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.2.1).

This extension **may** be present (it's not mandatory) and **may** contain the URL to get the issuer's certificate (**issuer** is the certificate "above" the current one, so the end entity's issuer is the intermediate, and the intermediate's issuer is the root).

You can get this extension value with BouncyCastle:

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AccessDescription;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AuthorityInformationAccess;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509ObjectIdentifiers;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil;

X509Certificate cert = // end entity certificate

// get Authority Information Access extension (will be null if extension is not present)
byte[] extVal = cert.getExtensionValue(Extension.authorityInfoAccess.getId());
AuthorityInformationAccess aia = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(extVal));

// check if there is a URL to issuer's certificate
AccessDescription[] descriptions = aia.getAccessDescriptions();
for (AccessDescription ad : descriptions) {
    // check if it's a URL to issuer's certificate
    if (ad.getAccessMethod().equals(X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_ad_caIssuers)) {
        GeneralName location = ad.getAccessLocation();
        if (location.getTagNo() == GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier) {
            String issuerUrl = location.getName().toString();
            // http URL to issuer (test in your browser to see if it's a valid certificate)
            // you can use java.net.URL.openStream() to create a InputStream and create
            // the certificate with your CertificateFactory
            URL url = new URL(issuerUrl);
            X509Certificate issuer = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(url.openStream());
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use this code with the end entity certificate to get the intermediate. Then you use it again with the intermediate to get the root.

Then you add the **root** to your `TrustAnchor` and the validation should work.

---

**Note:** But as I said, this extension is not mandatory and may not be present. In this case, `getExtensionValue` will return `null`, and the only alternative that I know is to search for the certificates in google and download them (those certificate chains are usually public and not hard to find)

Comment: The extension Authority Info Access is quite common for OCSP info. But I think I've never seen a certificate with this extension containing  id-ad-caIssuers. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @Egl I've seen certificates with both id-ad-caIssuers and OCSP (google.com's certificate and Brazil's PKI end entities are good examples). I've also seen certificates with just one of them, unfortunately it seems that there's no standard among the CA's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You helped me a lot!

Comment: Can you please clarify following - as I understood, the end-point certificate doesn't contain information about the issuers (up to the root) chain, windows (idk what about other systems) only makes it look just as if does (when you check "Certification path" tab while checking certificate info). So whenever I click certification path, windows rebuilds this chain also? Or for example, mail clients as thunderbid or outlook for example, are doing the same work when checking mail signature?

Comment: @Hugo, I'm very grateful, once again. It compiled and it works, but I still feel like going through darkness, there are so many things I do not fully understand and it bugs me a lot. Can you please recommend something to read? I was thinking about David Hook's  "Beginning Cryptography with Java", but it's kinda outdated (2005). I have basic understanding of cryptography, not really completely newb, but very far away from a pro also.

Comment: Windows comes with lots of pre-installed certificate chains, from Authorities that are part of [Microsoft Root Program](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx), so Windows is not rebuilding the chain - it already has it installed as a trusted authority. Other softwares can choose to use this windows pre-installed list of certificates (aka "Repository" or "Trust store"), or have a separate list (firefox, for example, has a list apart from Windows).

Comment: I believe that Outlook uses Windows repository. Thunderbird and Firefox probably share the same repository (separate from Windows). Java also has its own repository (in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`), but I think it's possible to merge it with Windows repository. Many application servers can use java cacerts or have its own as well (some allow you to have different truststores per instance). Anyway, every software (usually) provides a way to add new certificates to its repositories (and it's usually documented). That's how a certificate chain is validated in any system/application.

Comment: I think you can start by studying [Public Key Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) and [Public Key Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). And don't worry, it took me years to really understand how all this stuff works (and I still don't feel like a pro, there's a lot of details that I don't have a deep understanding). Anyway, if you understand how (and why) it works, that's enough for most applications (you don't need to learn all the math details, they're already implemented in the API's)

Comment: One more thing: as I said, the end entity certificate **might** contain information about its issuer (in the AIA extension, as explained in the answer). But it doesn't contain information about the whole chain. You must go through each step: end entity to intermediate, then intermediate to another intermediate, until you get the root (there are theoretically no limit to the number of intermediates, I believe, but 1 or 2 are the most common cases). But some intermediates might not have information about its issuer (it's not mandatory), and that's really annoying..

Comment: `X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue` is now replaced by `JcaX509ExtensionUtils.parseExtensionValue` (I haven't tested whether it works)

Answer (score 2):

btw, if we have out certificate installed in windows, everything is much simpler:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, null);
String alias = "your alias";
ArrayList<X509Certificate> certsChain = new ArrayList<>();
if (ks.isCertificateEntry(alias)) {
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    System.out.println("Chain length: " + chain.length);
        for(Certificate c : chain) certsChain.add((X509Certificate)c);
}

Collections.reverse(certsChain);
certsChain.forEach(MainClass::printDBG);
```

boom, and the whole certificates chain is ready