# Get signing chain from CMSSignedData

Tags: java, bouncycastle, sign, verify, chain

How can I get a signing chain from a `CMSSignedData` (BouncyCastle) to verify it with the signing chain store?

```
Certificate[] storeCertChain = store.getCertificateChain(alias)
```

Isn't there a command or something like this I can get the signing chain of the data? Or get the certificate from it and there from the signing chain?

Answer (score 3):

The chain of the certificate used to sign **might** be in the `CMSSignedData`, but it's not mandatory.

According to [RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852), a CMS SignedData has the [following structure (described in section 5.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852#section-5.1):

```
SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
    encapContentInfo EncapsulatedContentInfo,
    certificates [0] IMPLICIT CertificateSet OPTIONAL,
    crls [1] IMPLICIT RevocationInfoChoices OPTIONAL,
    signerInfos SignerInfos }
```

The `certificates` field is described as:

> certificates is a collection of certificates. It is intended that
> the set of certificates be sufficient to contain certification
> paths from a recognized "root" or "top-level certification
> authority" to all of the signers in the signerInfos field. **There
> may be** more certificates than necessary, and **there may be**
> certificates sufficient to contain certification paths from two or
> more independent top-level certification authorities. **There may
> also be fewer certificates than necessary**, if it is expected that
> recipients have an alternate means of obtaining necessary
> certificates (e.g., from a previous set of certificates).  The
> signer's certificate **MAY** be included.

Note that the `certificates` field is optional, and even when it's present, all its contents are also optional. So, this field **might** contain the certificate chain, but it's not guaranteed.

**If** this field is present, you can get it with **BouncyCastle** (I'm using version **1.56**):

```
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

CMSSignedData sigData = ...
Store store = sigData.getCertificates();
```

When there are no certificates, I'm not sure if `getCertificates()` returns `null` or an empty `Store` (I think it may vary according to implementation).

If the `Store` is not `null`, you can check if the signer's certificate is present:

```
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationStore;

SignerInformationStore signers = sigData.getSignerInfos();
Collection<SignerInformation> c = signers.getSigners();
for (SignerInformation signer : c) {
    // this collection will contain the signer certificate, if present
    Collection signerCol = store.getMatches(signer.getSID());
}
```

The `signerCol` collection will contain the signer certificate, **if** it's present in the `certificates` field. Then you can use it to verify the signature, exactly like you were doing [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43995011/7605325).

To check if the whole chain is in the CMS structure, you can get all the certificates in the `Store` and check if they're there.
To get everything inside a `Store`, you can use code similar to used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44026076/7605325):

```
Collection<X509CertificateHolder> allCerts = store.getMatches(null);
```

In the version I'm using (**BouncyCastle 1.56**), passing `null` returns all the certificates in the store. You can then check if the chain is inside the `allCerts` collection.

If the chain is not present, you'll have to get it elsewhere.

- if you have the signer's (end entity) certificate, you can try it using the Authority Information Access (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893412/7605325))
- if it's not possible, you have to download the chain or get the certificates with the signer